# addImage error (Cannot read property 'addImage' of undefined) in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am developing an elearning course with the possibility of downloading certificate after successful completion of the course. I am using jsPDF and everything works OK, I am able to copy the variable from the course to pdf, I am able to save the pdf, but I ran into problem when I try to add a background image.

I am not an expert in JavaScript, so I am following the documentation properly. I am able to load the scripts into html, the javascript code works perfectly except the addimage function, it always gives the "Cannot read property 'addImage' of undefined" and crashes the script.

This is the javascript I am using:

```
var player = parent.GetPlayer();
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
var certif = player.GetVar("cert");

if (certif == 1) {
   parent.backgroundimage ();
 }
var namename = player.GetVar("input1");
 doc.setFontSize(18);
 doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);
 doc.setFontStyle("bold");
 doc.text(17, 55, namename);

doc.save('Certificate.pdf');
```

Here is separate javascript (image.js) for the backgroundimage function which I saved separately because Articulate Storyline does not directly support Base64.

```
function backgroundimage() {
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,... string with over 120.000 characters'
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 223)
}
```

And here are the scripts I am including in the head of the html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.5.3/dist/jspdf.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="image.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Everything seems to work OK, I can create, save the pdf, position the text, I can call the function "backgroundimage" (tested it with console.log) I only get an error when I include the doc.addimage. I have tested with the addimage.js included in jspdf but without result. I used downloaded javascripts, and I have tried with jspdf.js only, probably all the possibilities I could think of, but no result.

Comment: addImage is not defined in jsPDF

Comment: It literally menas that `doc` in your `backgroundimage()` function is undefined. Check your code again.